# Why does Alexa's Android app show a red exclamation point for my site's "Rank in Indonesia"?

Tags: seo, ranking, alexa

There is a red exclamation mark for my website when I view the it from Alexa Android app.  The mark appears above "Rank in Indonesia".

[image]
What is causing that red exclamation mark to appear? A few weeks ago, that exclamation mark wasn't there.

Comment: Did you mouseover it? If there is a message associated with that icon that usually tells you what it is.

Comment: I cannot tell you what the icon represents, but I do wonder why you are putting stock in Alexa at all?? It is most notorious for being the junkiest of the junk rank sites. It is absolutely impossible for Alexa to know the rank of any site since by their own admittance they are not able to track 1/3rd of all traffic even if everyone (that could) used Alexa. From a statistical analysis perspective, you cannot extrapolate from what you do not know and Alexa really cannot know much based upon the numbers. I would drop the app like it's hot and sign up with Google. But that is just me. Amen?

Comment: @john No i didn't mouse over it, because i open it from Alexa Android Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it is supposed to be the Indonesian flag in that location.   The exclamation appears to be because the flag didn't load and does not indicate a problem with your website.

The [Alexa website shows similar info](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/puali.com) and is able load a flag image in roughly the same place.

[image]

If I mouse over the image of the flag, I get the tool tip "Indonesian flag".

Comment: Okay thanks for the information, first i think that exclamation is to inform that my site rank is getting worse than yesterday.